# Selenium xpath Google search

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Selenium webdriver is unable to find element like google search button using xpath.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button [@type='button']")).click();

Comment: There are no opening double-quotes in your code. Also target button is dynamic, so you need to wait until it appeared in DOM\

Comment: Even same problem exists

Comment: It's not working bro..

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//following::*[@value='Google Search'][2]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this finding the button by text.
`".//button[text()='some text']"`